# Character escape sequences for ">"

Tags: xss

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Character_escape_sequences) gives all character escape sequences for "<". Where can I find a similar list for ">"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ASCII `<` is 0x3c (60 decimal). The ASCII `>` is 0x3e (62 decimal), so the list would be:

```
>
%3e
&gt
&gt;
&GT
&GT;
&#62
&#062
&#0062
&#00062
&#000062
&#0000062
&#62;
&#062;
&#0062;
&#00062;
&#000062;
&#0000062;
&#x3e
&#x03e
&#x003e
&#x0003e
&#x00003e
&#x000003e
&#x3e;
&#x03e;
&#x003e;
&#x0003e;
&#x00003e;
&#x000003e;
&#X3e
&#X03e
&#X003e
&#X0003e
&#X00003e
&#X000003e
&#X3e;
&#X03e;
&#X003e;
&#X0003e;
&#X00003e;
&#X000003e;
&#x3E
&#x03E
&#x003E
&#x0003E
&#x00003E
&#x000003E
&#x3E;
&#x03E;
&#x003E;
&#x0003E;
&#x00003E;
&#x000003E;
&#X3E
&#X03E
&#X003E
&#X0003E
&#X00003E
&#X000003E
&#X3E;
&#X03E;
&#X003E;
&#X0003E;
&#X00003E;
&#X000003E;
\x3e
\x3E
\u003e
\u003E
```

An [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) and [HTML code table](https://www.lookuptables.com/) can go a long way.